# Search item in MySQL tree with many to many association

Tags: php, mysql, search, doctrine-orm, tree

We are using Doctrine 2 for database access with [tree extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md).

First table is tree table with locations of European Union created from this [source](https://github.com/Aulinks/data-locations).

**Location table:**

```
id
name
parent
lft
rgt
lvl
root
companies
```

There is also company table which holds list of companies with many to many relation to location table. These locations are locations where given company acts. It can be country (level 0), some region (level 1, 2, 3, 4) or just some city, town or vilage (level 5).

**Company table:**

```
id
name
locations
```

Than we have got one search form for companies with location select.

Now I need to create DQL which will select all countries in given location (nested).

So when I choose for example whole country, it should select all companies in this country, in regions in this country and also in cities or towns in this country.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

<del>I added "auto-adding" (maybe temporary) of parent locations into companies. It will just walk through all parents and add them. So when company acts in city and user choose whole country or region, this company will be displayed.</del>

<del>Unfortunately there is still one problem. If some company acts in whole country and user choose city in this country, company will not be displayed.</del>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching is not so expensive and people will search in just few locations in one search query.

So the first thing I do, is to load ids of all searched locations and also ids of all their parents.

**Getting parents' ids:** *`BaseTreeFacade::getPathIds`*

```
public function getPathIds($entity)
{
    $ids = $this->getPathQueryBuilder($entity)
        ->select('node.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR);

    return array_map('current', $ids);
}
```

this method returns simple array with ids. Now I have to join ids from search query with parents' ids.

**Expanding ids:** *`Helpers::expandTreeValues`*

```
public static function expandTreeValues(BaseTreeFacade $facade, array $values)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($values as $id) {
        $entity = $facade->findOneById($id);

        $result[] = [$id];
        $result[] = $facade->getPathIds($entity);
    }

    $result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);
    $result = array_unique($result, SORT_NUMERIC);

    return $result;
}
```

Next step is creating where clause for searching in locations and theirs children.

**Creating where clause:** *`Helpers::prepareWhereClauseForChildren`*

```
public static function prepareWhereClauseForChildren(BaseTreeFacade $facade, array $values)
{
    $where = [];
    $parameters = [];

    foreach ($values as $id) {
        $entity = $facade->findOneById($id);

        $where[] = "(l.lvl > :level$id AND l.id > :left$id AND l.id < :right$id)";

        $parameters["left$id"] = $entity->lft;
        $parameters["right$id"] = $entity->rgt;
        $parameters["level$id"] = $entity->lvl;
    }

    $where = implode(' OR ', $where);

    return (object) [
        'where' => $where === '' ? null : $where,
        'parameters' => count($parameters) === 0 ? null : $parameters,
    ];
}
```

There I can search in all sub-locations because of left and right branches of tree. Last step is to update original `QueryBuilder` with where clause created in previous step.

**Finalizing QueryBuilder:** *`Helpers::updateWithTreeEntity`*

```
public static function updateWithTreeEntity(QueryBuilder $qb, array $values, $addWhere = null, array $addParameters = null)
{
    if ($addParameters === null) {
        $addParameters = [];
    }

    $addParameters['locations'] = $values;
    $appendQuery = $addWhere === null ? '' : " OR $addWhere";

    $qb->andWhere("l.id IN (:locations)$appendQuery");

    foreach ($addParameters as $key => $value) {
        $qb->setParameter($key, $value);
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
public function createQueryBuilderForSearchingInLocations(array $locations)
{
    $gb = $this->createQueryBuilderSomehow();
    $facade = $this->getLocationsFacadeSomehow();

    $locations = Helpers::expandTreeValues($facade, $locations);
    $where = Helpers::prepareWhereClauseForChildren($facade, $locations);

    Helpers::updateWithTreeEntity($qb, $locations, $where->where, $where->parameters);

    return $qb;
}
```